# How to Remove the Ads with the help of in-app purchase in flutter app

Tags: flutter, admob, in-app-purchase

I want to Disabled Admob Ads After User Purchase the Package for Remove Ads with Help in-app Purchase. I want to Remove Interstitial Ads and Rewarded Ads, Below is the Code for Interstitial and Rewarded Ads:

```
  InterstitialAd myInterstitial = InterstitialAd(
    adUnitId: Platform.isIOS ? ios_ads : android_ads,
    listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
      print("InterstitialAd event is $event");
    },
  );

  myInterstitial
    ..load()

    ..show(
      anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      anchorOffset: 0.0,

    );
```

**Rewarded Ad**

```
 RewardedVideoAd.instance.listener =
      (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
    if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {

    }
  };
  RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(adUnitId: Platform.isIOS ? ios_ads : android_ads, 
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo).then((v){

    print("log "+v.toString());
    if(v){
      RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();

    }

  });
```

Comment: Anybody Can help still I couldn't found the solution for it....

Answer (score -3):

Have a boolean to keep track of whether payment is made to remove ads or not. If this boolean is set to true, then don't call the ads code.

```
if(!isPaymentDone){
  // code to show ads
}
```

Comment: can you share more information, how can I remove ads with in-app purchase